# Ocaml: unicode string length

Tags: unicode, ocaml

In OCaml, how can I compute the length of a string that may have unicode encodings ?  To give an example, here is my problem:

```
utop # "\u{02227}";;
- : string = "∧"
utop # Caml.String.length "\u{02227}";;
- : int = 3
utop # Base.String.length "\u{02227}";;
- : int = 3
```

and I would like to obtain the obvious answer: 1.

Comment: [This discussion](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/unicode-support-in-objective-caml-runtime-system/4979/5) recommends using https://github.com/yoriyuki/Camomile or https://erratique.ch/software/uutf.

Comment: Note that you can install Camomile or uutf using OPAM: https://opam.ocaml.org

Comment: What _is_ "the obvious answer"? I guess it's not bytes, since you don't seem happy with that, but it could be code points, code units, graphemes or glyphs? It's not obvious to me what you want, since you're providing a very contrived example with no real use case for context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to count the number of extended grapheme clusters (aka a graphical character), you can use `uuseg`. For instance

```ml
let len = Uuseg_string.fold_utf_8 `Grapheme_cluster (fun x _ -> x + 1) 0
let n = len "∧";;
```

returns

> val n : int = 1